# Eigenvalues of a particular Gram matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

the Gram matrix of a set of vectors $\boldsymbol{v}_1,\dots,\boldsymbol{v}_{n}$ is the matrix of entries $G_{ij}=\left\langle \boldsymbol{v}_{i},\boldsymbol{v}_{j}\right\rangle$. It is well known that its eigenvalues are non-negative. If we assume that the vectors $\boldsymbol{v}_1,\dots,\boldsymbol{v}_{n}$ satisfy the conditions
\begin{equation}
\left\lVert \boldsymbol{v}_i \right\rVert=1, \quad \langle \boldsymbol{v}_i,\boldsymbol{v}_j\rangle>0, \quad i,j=1,\dots,n,
\end{equation}
it is true that its eigenvalues are greater than $1$?

Comment: This is impossible -- check the trace (Schatten 1 norm) or the Frobenius norm (Schatten 2 norm)

Answer (score 2):

It is not satisfied with the mentioned conditions for example if $\boldsymbol{v}_1=\boldsymbol{v}_{2}$ for $2\times 2$ matrix.
Then we have rank $1$ matrix henceforth one of eigenvalues must be equal $0$.

Comment: Additionally, we can present the exact formula for $2\times 2$ matrices:   $\    $ $\lambda_{1,2}=1\pm \cos\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the angle between vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$.